# Hosting Server Side of android messenger OpenShift

Tags: java, openshift

I am trying to host the server side of my android messenger on Openshift, and have deployed the application listening on port 8080. I try to connect to the server using the URL of my app and port 80. The client side says its connected, but it is not interacting with the server program. What could be the issue? On the server side I am using ServerSocket to listen and send messages.

Answer (score 0):

Any traffic to port 80 gets sent through an apache reverse proxy, so it will be interpreted as web traffic.  You could hit it on port 8000 and then use websockets on the inside of your gear (which still need to listen on port 8080), but it will be websockets traffic, not plain tcp socket traffic.

Your best bet would be to either use websockets, or write an API over http that your application can interact with.

Comment: Are there any resources regarding how to implement an API over HTTP which interacts with my application?

Comment: Try searching google for "some_language + how to write an api" and replace some_language with what language you want to use.

Comment: What language would the API have to be written with in order to accept data from the client programs and pass it on to the server program?

Comment: It could be any language that you want to use for your api on your openshift gear, then you connect to your RESTful api from your android application

Comment: Could I re-write my server application in Python this time and use the Python web-sockets? Would this work properly on OpenShift?

Comment: Yes, listen on port 8080, and access them externally on port 8000 or 8443

Comment: When I push that program to OpenShift the incoming traffic will come right to the new program; correct?